# ASP.NET Core IActionResult returning random content in Chrome

Tags: http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create an IActionResult in ASP.NET Core to handle [range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) to serve content to HTML5 media players.

I think I got the implementation, and it seems to be working when called with basic user agents like cURL or wget, but when it's called by Chrome to fetch the content for an audio tag, it never works.

I manually checked the returned contents with the physical files to be sure I'm serving the right content, and it seems to be working.

Full content request check:

```
dd ibs=1 if=CA98AF68-766B-457C-828E-DB3B8C2A57BE.webm 2> /dev/null | \
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | \
openssl enc -base64 -A
80AE1Im8ebN12f3te7UvBcug7DkGluam21wgL7zJ4h4=

curl --range 0- --silent http://localhost:3038/Media/CA98AF68-766B-457C-828E-DB3B8C2A57BE/webm | \
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | \
openssl enc -base64 -A
80AE1Im8ebN12f3te7UvBcug7DkGluam21wgL7zJ4h4=
```

Ranged content request check:

```
dd ibs=1 if=CA98AF68-766B-457C-828E-DB3B8C2A57BE.webm count=1024 2> /dev/null | \
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | \
openssl enc -base64 -A
SFAoua0OkQ3ZbEnXXd42CqcucQdkOTxpkjQwBNKOF7Y=

curl --range 0-1024 --silent http://localhost:3038/Media/CA98AF68-766B-457C-828E-DB3B8C2A57BE/webm \
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | \
openssl enc -base64 -A
SFAoua0OkQ3ZbEnXXd42CqcucQdkOTxpkjQwBNKOF7Y=
```

The hashes of the physical file chunks and of the content returned by ASP.NET are identical both for full files and partial files, so I think the code is correct.

However Chrome is calling the exactly same URI it gets random data: sometimes more, sometime less, sometimes a request aborted is raised and a task canceled exception thrown.

Request with 80.2 kilobytes returned:

[image: A request with 80.2 kilobytes returned.]

Request with 196 bytes returned:

[image: A request with 196 bytes returned.]

Request with 132 kilobytes returned:

[image: A request with 132 kilobytes returned]

Task canceled exception raised:

[image: A raised task canceled exception.]

The implementation is pretty straightforward, it supports (for now) only single-ranged requests and no bells or whistles (the following code is a simple sandbox and in no way production ready).

This is the ranged action result implementation:

```cs
namespace Sandbox.Results
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Headers;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
    using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

    public class StreamingActionResult : IActionResult, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly string contentType;
        private readonly FileStream stream;

        public StreamingActionResult(IFileInfo fileInfo, string contentType)
        {
            this.stream = new FileStream(fileInfo.PhysicalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous);
            this.contentType = contentType;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

            RequestHeaders requestHeaders = context.HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders();

            if (requestHeaders.Range == null)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentLength = this.stream.Length - this.stream.Position;
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = this.contentType;
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;

                await this.stream.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body, 4096, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);

                return;
            }

            if (requestHeaders.Range.Unit != "bytes" || requestHeaders.Range.Ranges.Count != 1)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;

                return;
            }

            RangeItemHeaderValue range = requestHeaders.Range.Ranges.First();

            this.stream.Seek(range.From.Value, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = this.contentType;
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;

            if (range.To.HasValue)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentLength = range.To.Value - range.From.Value;
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", $"bytes {range.From.Value:D}-{range.To.Value:D}/{this.stream.Length:D}");

                await StreamCopyOperation.CopyToAsync(this.stream, context.HttpContext.Response.Body, range.To.Value - range.From.Value, 4096, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            }
            else
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentLength = this.stream.Length - range.From.Value;
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", $"bytes {range.From.Value:D}-{this.stream.Length:D}/{this.stream.Length:D}");

                await this.stream.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body, 4096, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                this.stream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the action result is used:

```cs
namespace Sandbox.Controllers
{
    using System;

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

    using Sandbox.Results;

    [Route("/Media")]
    public class MediaController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment environment;

        public MediaController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            this.environment = environment;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}/{format}")]
        public IActionResult Get([FromRoute] Guid id, [FromRoute] string format)
        {
            IFileInfo fileInfo = this.environment.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo($"Media\\{id:D}.{format}");

            return new StreamingActionResult(fileInfo, $"audio/{format}");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how the media element is declared:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sandbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sandbox</h1>
        <audio controls preload="metadata">
            <source src="/Media/CA98AF68-766B-457C-828E-DB3B8C2A57BE/webm" type="audio/webm" />
            <p>Your browser does not support audio content.</p>
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't understand what is wrong, if it's something in my code, something in Chrome or something else entirely.